# Getting different between two variable of type time in Sql

Tags: sql, time, procedure

I want to ask how to find the different between 2 variable that have datatype time(7) time in minute.
**Example :**

```
DECLARE @time1 time(7)
DECLARE @time2 time(7) = CONVERT(time(7),GETDATE())
DECLARE @difftime int
SET @difftime = @time2-@time1
```

i wonder to do this any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Datediff function for finding difference.

It can be done in different way also, it is just one way to do it..

```
----query start---
DECLARE @time1 time(7) = '16:02:27.5930000'
DECLARE @time2 time(7) = CONVERT(time(7),GETDATE()) 
Declare @diffint int = 0
select @diffint = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, convert(datetime,@time1), convert(datetime,@time2)) 

select @diffint  [Diff in min],convert(datetime,@time1) as time1, convert(datetime,@time2) as time2

----query end ---
```